# Delete data frame specific data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I loaded the csv file and got a specific column in the form of a list.
The length of the list is 6871.
In order to shorten the length of the list, I want to delete the rest of the list, leaving only the 10th element of the list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('data_science/pro_data.csv', sep='\t')

layer_list = data['z'].drop_duplicates()   
layer_list = np.array(layer_list.tolist())
print(layer_list)
print(type(layer_list))
print(len(layer_list))

for idx in range(len(layer_list):            
    if not(idx % 10 == 0):
        layer_list = np.delete(layer_list, idx)

print(len(layer_list))
```

```
[out]
[255.092 255.49  255.622 ... 432.091 432.341 432.591]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
6871
```

But I get the following error:

```
[Error]
IndexError: index 3617 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3616
```

The elements of the list are:
`[255.092 255.49  255.622 ... 432.091 432.341 432.591]`

Please tell me how to fix this error or else

Comment: From the list do you need only the 10th element or elements in multiples of 10, i.e element at index 10, 20 etc. It will be great if you can provide input and output.

Comment: I don’t just need the 10th row
This is the assumption that we had to reduce the number of data and I only need to randomly extract 10 times the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is making this more complicated.than it needs to be. There is no need to try to delete rows in a loop. You should just create a range spaced by 10 and select the elements you want.

Also, any pandas series exposes the underlying numpy array with `values`, so there is no need to convert to a list and then to a numpy array.

```
idx = np.arange(10, len(data) // 10 * 10, step=10)
s = data['z'].drop_duplicates().iloc[idx]
```

Comment: Thank you!
I was able to refer to the problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiples of 10 from a list.

```
l = np.arange(21)
print(list) # [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20]
l[10::10] # array([10, 20])
```

We are slicing the list from 10th element and thereafter fetching every 10th element.

Comment: Thank you!
It was a lot easier to solve the problem!